# Cloud infrastructure modeling capability

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, cloud-foundry, openstack

What are the graphical tool/s that is tailored for a cloud based solution infrastructure modeling? I mean something that you can visualize say your cloud infrastructure deployment in say aws. I can sure do that say in MS Visio or similar generic drawing tools but I am wondering if there any options that is tailored for cloud infrastructure modeling? Also, anything open source? If nothing, what is the closest thing that I can change to make it do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple infrastructure vizualisation tool for AWS infrastructure called [Nephorider](http://www.nephorider.com). It is currently in Beta by invitation

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/) has a visual interface for deploying and managing software services that run in a cloud infrastructure. Here's a [blog post](http://www.jorgecastro.org/2012/10/16/announcing-the-juju-web-ui/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Juju's mechanism is an interactive GUI for manipulating the structure - it doesn't quite let you "draw it out" with a visio-like interface, but it's probably the closest thing to that solution set at this point that's open source.

There's some commercial products that do something like this ([CA purchased 3tera and their AppLogic platform](http://www.ca.com/us/cloud-platform.aspx) - which operates much like this).

I'm not aware of any tools to generate AWS CloudFormation structures from a visual UI.